# Combobox do VBA/Excel : desativar o Auto-Completar

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, combobox

Estou digitando um texto que está em um **ComboBox** do **VBA/Excel**, mas a parte inicial do texto coincide com outro já incluído na lista, além dele completar automaticamente (o que não quero), ele altera a posição da lista (o índice).

Tem como travar isso? Para ao digitar ele não trazer outro texto que coincida?

Exemplo: na lista do **ComboBox** existe as cores AMARELO, AZUL e VERMELHO e vou incluir "VERDE", ao iniciar a digitar, ele completa automaticamente para "VERMELHO", já que as iniciais coincidem, porém, se corrijo e digito VERDE, ele já alterou o índice (ComboBox.TopIndex) para a posição do VERMELHO (irá substituir um pelo outro, o que também não quero).

Se VERMELHO está em maiúsculo e eu quiser escrever em minúsculo, ele sempre traz em maiúsculo.

**Tem como travar este complemento automático?**

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem como sim, para isto vamos criar um ComboBox temporário para interagir, pois, precisamos de um componente editável para isto e a Lista não é editável!

Mãos a obra!

1. Crie uma lista qualquer com algumas opções em Maiúsculo e Minúsculo
   (que é seu caso).
2. Agora, abra a Aba Desenvolvedor (se não estiver disponível, Abra o
   Menu Arquivo/Opções/Personalize a Faixa de Opções). Insira em
   qualquer local um **Controle ActiveX ComboBox** e altere seu nome
   para **ComboBoxTemp**.
3. Ainda na aba Desenvolvedor, clique sobre o botão Visual Basic, de um
   clique duplo sobre a planilha onde esta o componente e a lista
   (atenção, é importante estar no local correto) e adicione (copie e
   cole) este código!

> ```
> Option Explicit
>
>
> Private Sub ComboBoxTemp_KeyDown(ByVal _
>         KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
>         ByVal Shift As Integer)
>
>     'Ocultar caixa de combinação e mover a próxima célula com Enter e Tab
>     Select Case KeyCode
>         Case 9
>             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
>         Case 13
>             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
>         Case Else
>             'Nada
>     End Select
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
>     Dim str As String
>     Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
>     Dim ws As Worksheet
>     Dim wsList As Worksheet
>
>     Set ws = ActiveSheet
>     Set wsList = Sheets(Me.Name)
>     Application.EnableEvents = False
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>     If Application.CutCopyMode Then
>       'Permite copiar e colar na planilha
>       GoTo errHandler
>     End If
>
>     Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBoxTemp")
>       On Error Resume Next
>       With cboTemp
>         .Top = 10
>         .Left = 10
>         .Width = 0
>         .ListFillRange = ""
>         .LinkedCell = ""
>         .Visible = False
>         .Value = ""
>       End With
>
>     On Error GoTo errHandler
>       If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
>         Application.EnableEvents = False
>         str = Target.Validation.Formula1
>         str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
>         With cboTemp
>             .Visible = True
>             .Left = Target.Left
>             .Top = Target.Top
>             .Width = Target.Width + 15
>             .Height = Target.Height + 5
>             .ListFillRange = str
>             .LinkedCell = Target.Address
>         End With
>         cboTemp.Activate
>
>         'Abrir a lista suspensa automaticamente
>         Me.ComboBoxTemp.DropDown
>         Me.ComboBoxTemp.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone 'Aqui faz acontecer o que você deseja
>         Me.ComboBoxTemp.AutoWordSelect = False
>         End If
>
> errHandler:
>   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
>   Application.EnableEvents = True
>   Exit Sub
>
> End Sub
> ```

Feche o Visual Basic, onde a Lista foi criada será substituída pelo ComboBox!

Faça os testes, aguardo o feedback!

Comment: Júnior, excelente, testei à parte as propriedades  MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone  e AutoWordSelect = False e deram o efeito desejado. Valeu pelo código e pelas dicas! Abraço.

Comment: Tranquilo Amigo!

Answer (score 0):

No **VBA** do **Excel** estas propriedades dão o resultado esperado quando "setadas" assim:

```
     MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone 

     AutoWordSelect = False
```